# How make "boost::stacktrace" work with Clang on Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace, boost-stacktrace

I am trying to use `boost::stacktrace` under Clang on Windows.

While it works with the MSVC compiler, using `clang-cl` instead it just outputs memory addresses like `0x00007FF63D371D14 in main.exe` instead of function names and line numbers like `foo at main.cpp:7`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

###### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    const auto stacktrace = boost::stacktrace::to_string(boost::stacktrace::stacktrace());
    std::cout << stacktrace;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

###### CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test_boost_traceback CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::boost)
```

###### Build commands

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

set BOOST_ROOT=C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_79_0
set PATH=C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Ninja;%PATH%

set CC=clang-cl
set CXX=clang-cl

mkdir build_clang_cl_debug 
cd build_clang_cl_debug
cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
ninja -v

main.exe
```

The build for MSVC is the same, just removing the lines that set `CC` and `CXX`, and leaving them unset.

Here is the output for MSVC:

```cpp
[1/2] C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1434~1.319\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  
/nologo /TP  -external:I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_79_0" -external:W0 
/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd -std:c++20 /showIncludes 
/FoCMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\main.dir\ 
/FS -c test_boost_traceback\main.cpp

[2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe 
--intdir=CMakeFiles\main.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe 
--mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  
-- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1434~1.319\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe 
/nologo CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj  /out:main.exe /implib:main.lib /pdb:main.pdb 
/version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  
kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib 
oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."

 0# boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> >
    ::init at C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_79_0\boost\stacktrace\stacktrace.hpp:76
 1# boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> >
    ::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> > at 
    C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_79_0\boost\stacktrace\stacktrace.hpp:129
 2# foo at test_boost_traceback\main.cpp:6
 3# main at test_boost_traceback\main.cpp:13
 4# invoke_main at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:79
 5# __scrt_common_main_seh at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
 6# __scrt_common_main at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:331
 7# mainCRTStartup at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp:17
 8# BaseThreadInitThunk in KERNEL32
 9# RtlUserThreadStart in ntdll
```

Here is the build commands and the output for Clang-cl:

```cpp
[1/2] C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\clang-cl.exe  
/nologo -TP  -imsvc"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_79_0" 
/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd -std:c++20 /showIncludes 
/FoCMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\main.dir\ 
-c -- test_boost_traceback\main.cpp

[2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe 
--intdir=CMakeFiles\main.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe 
--mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  
-- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\lld-link.exe 
/nologo CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj  /out:main.exe /implib:main.lib /pdb:main.pdb 
/version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  
kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib 
oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."

 0# 0x00007FF626A71D24 in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 1# 0x00007FF626A71041 in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 2# 0x00007FF626A71121 in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 3# 0x00007FF626A78059 in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 4# 0x00007FF626A7818E in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 5# 0x00007FF626A7820E in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 6# 0x00007FF626A7822E in test_boost_traceback\build_clang_cl_debug\main.exe
 7# 0x00007FFA41D774B4 in C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
 8# 0x00007FFA42DA26A1 in C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

I tried some of the build options in the [boost stacktrace documentation](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html). They all lead to some errors and I am not sure which one applies to Windows and Clang-cl.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

MSVC uses `WinDbg` which is shipped with the compiler.

This also works under `clang-cl` but we need to define the macro `BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_WINDBG` and specifically link to `ole32.lib` and `dbgeng.lib` as described [here](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html).

For CMake we achieved this by adding this (`main` being our target):

```
target_link_options(main PRIVATE dbgeng.lib)
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_WINDBG)
```

The `ole32.lib` is automatically linked.

This works for both the `Debug` and `RelWithDebInfo`. It doesn't work with `Release` as this strips all the symbols, but that's the same for MSVC.